# Perpetual NativeScript Mac Installation Issues

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I could really use someone's help on this as I have been troubleshooting this for a really long time now with no remediation.

The issue is simply installing the NativeScript CLI onto my OSX Yosemite Mac. I followed the steps according to NS' website (installing proper Node.JS version, downloaded Xcode 7.2 (due to OS constraints), installed JSDK, installed NS Sidekick, installed Android Studio w/ proper SDK along with every other required dependancy.

However, when I run "sudo npm i -g nativescript --unsafe-perm" (otherwise it will throw a EACCES error), I get the following log with it saying I missing all of these dependencies I know I have but it is claiming I don't.

The biggest kick is that while it still will say NativeScript successfully installed, whenever I run any tns command (like tns doctor), the bash command cannot be found.

I have made sure to follow the directions of adding NS to my path as well as my Android and Java SDKs. Here is the full log:

```
jsmbp:~ Js$ sudo npm i -g nativescript --unsafe-perm
Password:
/Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/bin/nativescript -> /Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
/Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/bin/tns -> /Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns

> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> nativescript@3.3.1 postinstall /Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node postinstall.js

WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

TIP: To avoid setting up the necessary environment variables, you can use the Homebrew package manager to install the Android SDK and its dependencies.

WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
You will not be able to build your projects for Android and run them in the native emulator.
To be able to build for Android and run apps in the native emulator, verify that you have
installed the latest Android SDK and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

TIP: To avoid setting up the necessary environment variables, you can use the Homebrew package manager to install the Android SDK and its dependencies.

WARNING: CocoaPods is not installed or is not configured properly.
You will not be able to build your projects for iOS if they contain plugin with CocoaPod file.
To be able to build such projects, verify that you have installed CocoaPods.
The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the ANDROID_HOME variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory.

Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.
Run $ sdkmanager to manage your Android SDK versions.

You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=26'.
Run $ sdkmanager from your command-line to install required Android Build Tools. In case you already have them installed, make sure ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set correctly.

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.
Run $ sdkmanager to manage the Android Support Repository. In case you already have it installed, make sure ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set correctly.

Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
You will not be able to build your projects for Android.
To be able to build for Android, verify that you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and configured it according to system requirements as
 described in http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-os-x.html#system-requirements

There seem to be issues with your configuration.
? Do you want to visit the official documentation? No
? Do you want to run the setup script? No
Your components are up-to-date: 
nativescript,tns-core-modules,tns-android,tns-ios

Autocompletion is already enabled

Installation successful. You are good to go. Connect with us on http://twitter.com/NativeScript.

+ nativescript@3.3.1
added 692 packages in 156.18s
jsmbp:~ Js$ tns doctor
-bash: tns: command not found
```

What can I do to fix this? npm also declares "rollbackFailedOptional" every time I try to reinstall after I uninstall it. Is npm caching a broken version and can I force it to do a genuine "reinstall?" It has been so frustrating as everything looks messed up and I really don't want to give up on NS. Let me know your thoughts and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by installing node.js correctly. I've you are having to you `--unsafe-perm` that means, the node.js installation is not done right.
I suggest you install `nvm` using homebrew and then install node from that. Please refer to my solution in this post https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/not-installing-on-macos/3292/4

Comment: So I followed this and now npm doesn't work when I call it to install NS. I got this when I installed node using your last step: "nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/Users/Jmsquillaro/.npm-packages"
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v8.9.1` to unset it.
Creating default alias: default -> 8.9.1 (-> v8.9.1)" What went wrong here and will this fix the problem at large? Was this caused by node.js or something else?

Comment: Did you uninstall your previous installation of node before you installed nvm?

Comment: Yes, and deleted any other files associated with it. Also did brew uninstall node for good measure. which node yielded nothing after this process so I assumed everything was deleted before following your tutorial.

Comment: What does, `node -v` and `npm -v` print now?

Comment: I ran "nvm use --delete-prefix v8.9.1" and now both node and npm work, displaying v8.9.1 for node and 5.5.1 for npm. When I went to run the install of NS again though, I was still given EACCES errors, even as root. When running the command like I did originally, with --unsafe-perm, I get the same exact thing as before. I feel like npm is just using a cache version of this somewhere. Again, this is not my area of expertise, so I am not sure. Is there anything else you think could remedy this or is there just something critically wrong in general?

Comment: Then clean cache using `npm cache verify`

Comment: I did this an ran it again with the "--unsafe-perm" (regular still had EACCES errors) and this time I believe the cli successfully installed (this never worked before)! It looks like tns doctor works. However, I believe the last issue I am having that was present in the originally is these issues with the android config. All of the android errors (not cocoapods or java) are still present. I downloaded Android Studio for this along with all of the relevant SDKs. I also believe I have set the path correctly as is in the NS docs. What is still wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: What are you not able to run now?

Comment: tns doctor works +  says these issues (truncated): "The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.

Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.

You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=26'.

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.

Comment: Are you using Zsh?

Comment: No I believe just bash as terminal was originally configured (have not modified my shell).

Comment: Also the ANDROID_HOME env variable was also repointed to where Android Studio 3 downloaded the SDK. This was saved through nano ~/.bash_profile. Its peculiar because it is only the Android specific elements to the install that are giving an issue. Everything else works fine now.

Comment: this is how my ANDROID_HOME env var looks like -> /Users/shiv19/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: By reformatting the env var, the tns doctor now yields no errors and I am able to build and run on the Android platform. Everything seems to be perfect except for the fact that I cannot build on ios. When I do tns run ios, I get "Searching for devices...
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Xcode build...
xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-quiet'" Unable to apply changes on device: 5d3917082e755838a5b920f9c2ccf5c1f7761149. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 64." Do you know what this could be caused by? I am running xcode 7.2 (due to os). Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: If you are using Xcode 7.3 as well as an older version of CocoaPods (0.39.0 or earlier), you must install the xcproj command-line tool by running `brew install xcproj` in your terminal. You can check your CocoaPods version with `pod --version`.

Comment: Strangely when I run "brew install xcproj" I get "Warning: xcproj 0.2.1 is already installed" and my Cocoapods version is "1.3.1," well above the requirement. Does anything else usually cause this issue? The ios build fails every time while Android has no problem. I am not sure if this error "xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-quiet'" is the actually issue or not. Searches yield little on it.

Comment: Did you also try `tns run ios --emulator`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately whether I run it on the device itself or the emulator, the build still fails. I am not sure if this is just a bug with Xcode 7.2 and the newest NS CLI or if there is a config problem. But tns doctor says everything is fine. Sadly I am limited by this Xcode version due to my os.

Comment: And is your os not upgradable any further?

Comment: At this point it probably would not be in the best interest of the hardware, which is why I'm trying to see if there is any fix I can do here but if not, I might have no choice. It fails because it doesn't know what the -quiet flag means. Very peculiar.

Comment: Then you can manually build it in xcode. By opening it from the xcodeproj file in platforms/ios folder

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. I think at this point the only resolve is goig to ah e to update my OS in order to get the higher version of Xcode, regardless of hardware limitations. Thank you for all of your help. By any chance, would you happen to know why after the NS CLI install, whenever I open terminal, it takes a much longer time and says many different things like xcodebuild, ruby, sh, git, etc. before saying bash? Sometimes this takes up to 30 seconds and is quite annoying since before it took only a second. Has this happened to you and is there a way to make it like it used to be?

Comment: I have never come across that problem. Not sure what is causing that.